# Humanizing the URL scheme when deploying a Spring app to a production environment

Tags: java, spring, .htaccess, tomcat, web.xml

I am a complete newbie, just starting with Spring.

I have developed a sample app which I want to deploy on a production environment. My problem is that my app serivces still look like that:

http://mydomain.com:8400/myserver/myapp/controller/view

I want to humanize this and turn it into something like that:

http://mydomain.com/controller/view

basically removing the port as well as the boilereplate /myserver/myapp/, since this domain will be used entirely for the purposes of that app

However, I still want to keep the existing url scheme as well.

How do I do that? do I have to configure server.xml (for the port), web.xml, .htaccess or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the port, you have at least 3 choices:

- let the container server (Tomcat or what ever) run on port 80
- use a Proxy Server (for example Apache Httpd) run on port 80 and forward the requests to your application Server (Tomcat)
- use some Firewall constraints to forward the requests fron port 80 to 8080

To get rid of the log path: you can use a combination of that ideas:

- (if you use an tomcat) rename the war to `ROOT.war` (uppercase) instead of `myapp.war`. Then you will get rid of the "myapp" part.
- Use some java framework like [tuckey UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to change the rest of the urls